# Why doesn't this for-loop ever execute?

Tags: java

On running this application and debugging the pointer does not enter the for loop. What could be the possible cause?

```
public char[] encryptUsingRot13(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    char a[] = new char[len];

    for (int i = 0; i > len; i++) {
        System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
        a[i] = s.charAt(i);
        System.out.println(a[i]);
    }

    for (int k = 0; k > len; k++) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j > len; j++) {
            if (a[k] == a[j]) {
                count++;
            }
            a[k] = (char) (a[k] + 13 + count - 1);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Your `for` loop conditions should be `i < len` and `k < len`. Your loop never runs because `i` and `k` start at 0, so they are never greater than the string's length and your looping condition is never met. Use less-than, instead of greater-than.

Comment: `i` is never greater then `len`. Fix your condition.

Answer (score 0):

logical Issue Try this..

```
public char[] encryptUsingRot13(String s) {
int len = s.length();
char a[] = new char[len];

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    System.out.println(s.charAt(i));
    a[i] = s.charAt(i);

    System.out.println(a[i]);
}
for (int k = 0; k < len; k++) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j > len; j++) {

        if (a[k] == a[j]) {

            count++;

        }
        a[k] = (char) (a[k] + 13 + count - 1);

    }
}

return a;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a logic mistake that is most likely due to a typing error:

What you do is

1. `int len = s.length()`
2. `int i=0`
3. while `i` is **greater** than `len` do something

Most likely `len` is already `> 0` and, therefore, the loops are not entered at all. As Yatish Agrawal pointed out the correct form for your loops would be
`for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)` and `for (int k = 0; k < len; k++)`.

You can replace the first loop by "char[] a = s.toCharArray();" if you don't care about the output.

Even though it is not applicable here, I recommend to look up *enhanced for* loops as they help to prevent these mistakes [see, e.g., here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).